# Will my experience give me ACS points?

Tags: australia, residency, skilled-migration

I have completed my engineering in Electronics and Communication Engineering.

I'm an IT professional with 5.5 years of experience. My current role is JAVA developer.

1. Will I get any points for experience?
2. Do I need to submit RPL?

Comment: What is RPL? The experience doesn't necessary match the degree but I don't know how strict Australia is on that.

Comment: All depends on your qualification - what is it exactly? BSc(Hons), Masters, Diploma, other?